# jqgrid: How to highlight all cells in the selected column?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Currently the default is to highlight the selected *row* (when you click a cell in the grid).

But I would like to be able to instead highlight an *entire column* when it is selected at the header for sorting. Then when the grid is sorted by a different column, change the previous column back to default and highlight the new sorted column.

Would be ideal if it just added a class to the column and then removed it when the sorting is changed to another column.

Comment: I wish we had some idea of what you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can find the column by which the table is sorted by checking for:

```
aria-selected="true"
```

on the various `<th>` elements in the table used for the column headers.

Then you will have to look in the table used for the actual result data and do something like:

```
tr.jqgrow td[aria-describedby="id_of_the_th_you_found_above"]
```

You see the `td` elements in the columns are linked to their `th` element by the `aria-describedby` attribute.

That should give you enough information to apply a style or whatever to the column you want.